# select specific item from data passed back by ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting data back in this format. (this is data output)

```
 { "proddata": "123" }{ "viewdata":
```

How can I select only specific data for example using data.proddata
Now I am getting data:undefined error when I try data.proddata.
Thank you.

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: You should return a single JSON object, like `{"proddata": "123", "viewdata": ...}`